# Mulesoft Dataweave use a map to update an object or use the update function or update operator

Tags: arrays, json, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have to update a value in a JSON object based on the variable "id". So in the next JSON array when the id = "746936" the isSendstatus property of that JSON object must be set to true.

This is my input

```
var xyz = [
  {
    "referenceId": "WRK-2403472",
    "taskReferenceId": "440827",
    "textMessages": [
      {
        "id": "746935",
        "isSendStatus": false,
        "message": "test1"
      },
      {
        "id": "746936",
        "isSendStatus": false,
        "message": "test2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "referenceId": "WRK-2403470",
    "taskReferenceId": "440828",
    "textMessages": [
      {
        "id": "746935",
        "isSendStatus": false,
        "message": "test3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And when I do a map and rebuild the JSON again with this code then it runs fine.

```
xyz map (item,index) -> {
    (referenceId : item.referenceId) if (item.referenceId != null),
    (taskReferenceId: item.taskReferenceId) if (item.taskReferenceId != null),
    (textMessages: item.textMessages map {
        id: $.id,
        isSendStatus: if(($.id == "746936") and (item.taskReferenceId == "440827")) true else  $.isSendStatus,
        message: $.message
    }) if (item.textMessages != null)
}
```

This is the right output:

```
[
  {
    "referenceId": "WRK-2403472",
    "taskReferenceId": "440827",
    "textMessages": [
      {
        "id": "746935",
        "isSendStatus": false,
        "message": "test1"
      },
      {
        "id": "746936",
        "isSendStatus": true,
        "message": "test2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "referenceId": "WRK-2403470",
    "taskReferenceId": "440828",
    "textMessages": [
      {
        "id": "746935",
        "isSendStatus": false,
        "message": "test3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But it is a lot of code and Mulesoft also has an update operator and function, I tried a couple of things like this but none of them give the right result:

```
// attempt 1
xyz map ($ update {
    case .textMessages["746936"].isSendStatus -> true
})
```

```
// attempt 2
xyz map(item,index) -> (item update ["textMessages"] with (if ($.id == "746936") 
        {
        id: $.id, 
        isSendStatus: true, 
        message: $.message
        } 
        else 
        $
    )
)
```

But when using the update operator or function it does not work. I think the problem is that the update function or operator has problems with arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not say it is a lot of code. Using the update operator may not reduce the size of the code, but perhaps more importantly for maintenance you could make changes that will communicate better the intention of the code.

Instead of null checks per key you can use filterObject() to remove all keys with null values.

The update operator doesn't has an issue with arrays.

Replacing the remaining condition with the update operator may be considered a question of style but it allows you to map only the fields that need to change.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json 
---
payload map (item,index) -> 
    item filterObject ((value, key, index) -> !(value is Null)) // remove all keys that have a null value
    update {
        case textMessages at .textMessages -> // update textMessages
            textMessages map ((message) -> message update { // update each item in textMessages
                    case status at .isSendStatus -> if((message.id == "746936") and (item.taskReferenceId == "440827")) true else status // update only the 
                })
    }
```

To test I added an item with null values.

Example input:

```json
[
  {
    "referenceId": "WRK-2403472",
    "taskReferenceId": "440827",
    "textMessages": [
      {
        "id": "746935",
        "isSendStatus": false,
        "message": "test1"
      },
      {
        "id": "746936",
        "isSendStatus": false,
        "message": "test2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "referenceId": "WRK-2403470",
    "taskReferenceId": "440828",
    "textMessages": [
      {
        "id": "746935",
        "isSendStatus": false,
        "message": "test3"
      }
    ]
  },
 {
    "referenceId": null,
    "taskReferenceId": "440828",
    "textMessages": null
  }
]
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "referenceId": "WRK-2403472",
    "taskReferenceId": "440827",
    "textMessages": [
      {
        "id": "746935",
        "isSendStatus": false,
        "message": "test1"
      },
      {
        "id": "746936",
        "isSendStatus": true,
        "message": "test2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "referenceId": "WRK-2403470",
    "taskReferenceId": "440828",
    "textMessages": [
      {
        "id": "746935",
        "isSendStatus": false,
        "message": "test3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "taskReferenceId": "440828"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks very much Aled, and you are right: It is not a reduction of code but it teaches me how to solve a problem like this with an update.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [`update function`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/latest/dw-values-functions-update) as opposed to the `update operator`. I find it cleaner with used with Arrays as you do not have to use `map` function to handle updation per element. It also makes the code more readable.

```js
%dw 2.0
import update from dw::util::Values
import indexWhere from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json
---
payload 
update "textMessages" with ((textMessages) -> 
    textMessages update (textMessages indexWhere  ($.id == "746936")) with ((textMessage) -> 
        textMessage update "isSendStatus" with true
        )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Harshank, it is a good solution if you look at my request, but the validation is only done on the "id" and not on the "taskMessageId" and it is better to do also a validation on taskMessageId == "440827" (in this example).

Comment: Oh, I did not catch that as you only added it in your code. In that case this would not add much to the other answer as you will still need to use map to do the update.